# how to speed up javascript/jquery for large inventory file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I use a mixture of jquery and javascript to search a bunch of items. 5000+ to be exact. I use a live search feature on my site which filters these items based on keywords. But because there are sooo many items to search through it lags, I would like to speed up this process.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#filter").keyup(function() {

            // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
            var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;

            // Loop through the list
            $(".inventory tr").each(function() {

                // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
                if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                    $(this).fadeOut();

                    // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
                } else {
                    $(this).show();
                    count++;
                }
            });

            // Update the count
            var numberItems = count;
            $("#filter-count").text("Number of items = "+count);
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" value="" />
        <span id="filter-count"></span>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<div class="inventory">
    <table> Stuff </table>
</div>
```

Is there anything I can do to speed it up? I really like this feature and would like to keep it on the site if possible.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to do 5000 searches? my first thought would be to reduce that to a smaller amount.

Comment: What browsers are you targeting? You can speed it up, by not using jQuery, every place you use jQuery.  This may be marginal, though.

Comment: First of all get rid of jQuery if you want speed in such volume scenarios, second skip the RegExp Constructor and use a regexp literal instead. If you still consider yo use jquery cache $(this) in a variable. Something like $this = $(this);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This little non-jquery baby parses 10000+ elements in about 50 ms.

```
function foo(){
    var nodes = document.evaluate('//table[@class="inventory"]//tr', document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null), 
    filterValue = document.getElementById('filter').value;

    if (nodes != null && filterValue != '') {
        var re = new RegExp(filterValue, "i"), count = 0;

        for (var m = 0; m < nodes.snapshotLength; m++){
            var item = nodes.snapshotItem(m);

            if(re.test(item.innerHTML.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '').trim())){
                count++;
                item.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                item.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }   

    }
    console.log("Parsed " + nodes.snapshotLength + " elements and matched " + count);
}


function time_my_script(script) {
    var start = new Date();
    script();
    return new Date() - start;
}

window.onload  = function() {
    var filter = document.getElementById('filter');
    filter.onkeyup=function(){ console.log("Time: " + time_my_script(foo) + "ms");} 
}
```

[image]

Html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
// ...
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="filter" name="filter" />

    <table class="inventory">
        <tr>
            <td>axxxasd</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="inventory">
        <tr>
            <td>axxxasd</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="inventory">
        <tr>
            <td>axxxasd</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="inventory">
        <tr>
            <td>asd</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great script.  Wouldnt it be more accurate with window.performance.now()?

Comment: This one is great too! I'm playing with it and it's much faster!

Comment: @carter You are probably right, I just wrote that as a simple hint. I'll update this example later on.

Comment: @user458474 Cool, let us know of your success :)

Answer (score 3):

1. jQuery is slower than vanilla JS; it's benefit is cross-browser
   support, but you don't need that for things like looping through
   objects
2. You're creating the same regex pattern inside the loop for
   each iteration; declare it once outside
3. It'd be faster to keep a copy of your table in memory and search there, rather than traversing the DOM each time.  That is, keep the data in an multidimensional array and scan that; then update the table view
4. There is already a jQuery plugin that will do this for you called [dataTables](http://www.datatables.net)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of dataTables. Totally forgot about that, though I feel that dataTables may be good for use in the future. For now, I'm using this as a simple theme, but Datatables will probably replace this whole thing within the next couple weeks. I just wanted to add a simple search feature for now.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to [debounce](http://unscriptable.com/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/) the search method:

1. Make it asynchronous to keep the UI functional
2. Make sure only one search is running at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I have no doubt that your code is currently slow, your search algorithm make extensive use of the DOM. At each key up on the keyboard you retrieve a list of node from a selector, this a very bad idea, you should not retrieve reference to DOM nodes more than once in a web application.

You should store the data you want to search outside of the DOM in a javascript object, and you might want also to use something like underscore's throttle to limit the rate at which your search function can be called.

See: http://underscorejs.org/#throttle, you could extract the function from the source code if you do not use underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using jQuery's built in contains function? I use it and it's quite fast. I use a version of contains function which is case insensitive.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // to make :contains case insensitive!!!
    $.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function (arg) {
        return function (elem) {
            return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
        };
    });

    $('#filter').on('input', function () {
        var $t = $(this);
        if ($t.val()) {
            $('.inventory tr').hide();
            $('.inventory').find('tr:Contains("' + $t.val() + '")').show();
        }
        else {
            $(".inventory tr").show();
        }
         $("#filter-count").text("Number of items = " + $(".inventory tr:visible").length);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Where would I put this code in my page? Do I replace it with the filter/input function that you mentioned above?

Comment: Just replace your document ready event handler with this one.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I don't know why. I'll edit the function above.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use the new jQuery. Just change the `on` to `bind` and it should work.

Comment: I just tried that and still not working. I have everything I am searching for in a table, so maybe that's why?

Comment: It should work. I can't debug your code remotely, I don't see what's happening there. You can play around with it until it works. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/csicky/tATEP/3/

Comment: How would I nestle this inside PHP? I figured out what I was doing wrong, but now I have a variable called HTML_body '' inside PHP which holds all my HTML. When I input this code, there are quotation errors. particularly with the + $t.val area of the code.

Comment: I don't know PHP, but escaping would be the solution. Something like this: `\"`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to cut the time to process in half, in some cases much more than that.  I am using the window.performance.now() in order to test the time.  In Chrome your script was running mostly around the 140ms time for me.  The longest case was 1400ms.  The script below was running around the 50ms-70ms and the longer the search phrase it seemed the faster the script(as low as 10ms). Let me know what you think (i put in a loop to fill up test data):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var startTime;
    var endTime;
    var i;
    var htmlString = "";

    for(i = 0; i < 5000; i += 1){
        htmlString += "<tr class='inventory'><td>This is my test thing</td></tr>";
    }

    $('#myTable').html(htmlString);


    $("#filter").keyup(function(){
        startTime = window.performance.now();
        // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
        var filter = $(this).val(),
        count = 0,
        matchedItems = $('tr.inventory td:contains("'+filter+'")'),
        nonMatchedItems = $('tr.inventory td').not(matchedItems),
        numItems = matchedItems.length;

        matchedItems.show();
        nonMatchedItems.hide();

        $("#filter-count").text("Number of items = "+numItems);

        endTime = window.performance.now();
        console.log(endTime - startTime);
    });
});
</script>
<form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" value="" />
        <span id="filter-count"></span>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div class="inventory">
<table id="myTable"></table></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that works great except...How would I go about putting a table with different shadings and column sizes. For Example:

    <table id="tableHeader" width="100%" border="0" align="center"   cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="overflow:auto"; >
    <tr>
       <td width="12%" height="21%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="style5"   Item No</td><tbody><tr>
    
 
 
     <tr>
        <td width="12%">A3228-12        </td>

Comment: assign a class to any field you want to perform search on, then change the matchedItems and nonMatchedItems selector accordingly.  e.g.  `$('tr.inventory td.searchable:contains("'+filter+'")'

Comment: OK I will play around w/it. Thanks.